# Is there any way to print only matching index elements?

Tags: arrays, perl, sorting, arraylist

**Given array:**

```
001;C;1;
066;S; ;1
```

And the code

```
my $query = "001";
my $query2 = "006";
```

If index in array..for example (001) matches query, then print the next elements in that row (C; 1) and not the whole array..Or If the next index (066) matches query print elements in that row (S;1) ...etc. My problem is..that I can't just type something like this.

```
 if (any {$_ eq $query} @found){
    print "@found2[1..2]\n";
}
```

..because my array is dynamic - once there are 20 elements next time 50 etc..

Any solutions? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is **some condition**? How do you define value of **$query**? Your code does not specify not **some condition** not **$query**. No answer can be given if question does not have clarity of the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean you have the following array:

```
my @rows = (
   '001;C;1;',
   '066;S; ;1',
);
```

It doesn't make sense to have individual variables for each query. Let's use an array for those too.

```
my @ids = ( '001', '006' );
```

The naïve solution would employ two nested loops, but that's extremely inefficient. We're going to create a hash that will allow us to efficiently check if an id is of interest.

```
my %ids = map { $_ => 1 } @ids;
```

Then, it's just a question of iterating over the array, parsing the fields, and checking if the id is relevant.

```
for my $row (@rows) {
    my ($id, @rest) = split(/;/, $row);
    say join(";", @rest) if $ids{$id};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So one solution is to iterate over the index of the Array:

```
my @ar = qw (001 C 1 006 S 2);

foreach my $index (0 .. $#ar-2) {
  if ($ar[$index] eq '001') {
    print @ar[$index+1 .. $index+2] , "\n";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are pretty close with what you said you just can't write something like:

```
 if (any {$_ eq $query} @found){
    print "@found2[1..2]\n";
}
```

The way I would do it, and I'm no professional by any means, would be to see if either query is found in the array by grepping for them. It would be easiest to make an array of the queries you are looking for to do this as well:

```
my @stuff = qw(001;C;1; 066;S; ;1);
my @queries = qw($query1, $query2);

foreach my $query (@queries) {
    if (my ($found) = grep { $_ =~ /(^$query\;.*)/ } @stuff) {
        print "$found\n";
    }
}
```

This assumes the first item to be delimited by the semicolon is a unique ID.